# Error while trying to get Unix file Permissions in Java6

Tags: java, unix

I want to read file permissions in unix and write the permissions to a csv file.
Here is my code:

```
           static void getFilePermissions(String fileName) {

    try {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls -lrt "+fileName + "| cut -c1-10");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                proc.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // getRecursiveFiles("/scratch/samaggar/SampleDir");
    getFilePermissions("/scratch/samaggar/SampleDir");
}
```

It gives me the IOException
Kindly suggest.I can't use Java7 which provides built in mechanism.

Comment: What's the stack trace? (You should also use the version of `exec()` that takes an array to pass the parameters in.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem starts here:

```
"ls -lrt "+fileName + "| cut -c1-10"
```

`Runtime.exec()` does NOT launch a shell, and therefore `|` is treated as an argument to your `ls` command. ALso, consider what will happen if the file name has a space in it.

Your second problem: you use `Runtime.exec()`; don't. Use a [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). It has very nifty methods for output redirections etc etc.

Your third problem: instead of piping through `cut`, just use Java's string methods to do that; it will be faster (no need to `fork()` for one).

Finally: have a look at the `stat` command and its `--format` option...

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestions.I am checking ProcessBuilder.In the meanwhile,I removed the cut command and used Java's string methods.Its working!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is already identified in the earlier answer- piping (`|`) to `cut` will not work from `Runtime.exec()`. Instead create a simple shell script e.g. `get_perm.sh` and put all your scripting code inside that shell script, then call this script from `Runtime.exec()`. It should work.